# Mouse coordinates relative to ImageIcon within a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, mouselistener, imageicon

I am building a desktop application in Java. I want to get the mouse coordinates of a mouse click relative to an image which is within a JSrollPane. The JScrollPane, screenScroll, is contained in a JPanel with a BorderLayout.

```
    final JLabel screenLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
    JScrollPane screenScroll = new JScrollPane(screenLabel);
    screenScroll.getViewport().setBackground(Color.white);

    screenLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override //I override only one method for presentation
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Y'all clicked at: "+e.getX() + ", " + e.getY()+" in the image.");
        }
    });
```

So here's the problem: the JPanel is larger than the image and the JScrollPane is taking up 100% of the JPanel (which looks nice, I'm happy about that) but the mousePressed event is giving me the coordinates relative to the JScrollPane/JPanel, not the image so the x coordinate is offset (even though the mouseListener was add to the JLabel containing the ImageIcon).

Hope I explained that clearly. How can I modify above code to get coordinates relative to image?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Thank you, @MadProgrammer. I didn't think it was necessary for this question, but in the future I will consider it.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you are trying to determine where the mouse click occurred relative to the actual image (`image`), which is displayed within the `JLabel`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.

Comment: Well, I'm still sitting here scratching me head over you question and it would make life (at least mine) simpler if I could replicate your problem - just saying...

Comment: Ahhh, can't be done...seriously...the position of the image is unknown and is actually up to the installed Look and Feel delegate....having said that, you could create your own image panel, which would allow you to maintain the information required to translate the mouse clicks...

Comment: I have no idea how I could do that, to be honest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, it would be very hard to achieve this using a `JLabel` as the actual position of the image is determined by the `JLabel`'s look and feel delegate.  While you could create your own delegate, you would end up needing to create one for each supported platform and...I'm too lazy...

Instead, you could create a custom component and render the image the way you want.  You would then be in a position to better ascertain the location of the image and convert the mouse point values you require, for example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    }

                    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\hold\\thumbnails\\MT015.jpg"));
                    final ImagePanel imgPane = new ImagePanel(img);
                    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(imgPane);
                    final JLabel report = new JLabel("...");

                    imgPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                            Point panelPoint = e.getPoint();
                            Point imgContext = imgPane.toImageContext(panelPoint);

                            report.setText("You clicked at " + panelPoint + " which is relative to the image " + imgContext);
                        }
                    });

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.add(scrollPane);
                    frame.add(report, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage img;

        public ImagePanel(BufferedImage img) {
            this.img = img;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return img == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        }

        protected Point getImageLocation() {

            Point p = null;
            if (img != null) {
                int x = (getWidth() - img.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - img.getHeight()) / 2;
                p = new Point(x, y);
            }
            return p;

        }

        public Point toImageContext(Point p) {
            Point imgLocation = getImageLocation();
            Point relative = new Point(p);
            relative.x -= imgLocation.x;
            relative.y -= imgLocation.y;
            return relative;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (img != null) {
                Point p = getImageLocation();
                g.drawImage(img, p.x, p.y, this);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more details

Comment: This looks like the solution. Still trying to wrap my head around the code, which is beautiful. Thank you so much for your time, MadProgrammer. One question, does this still work when the image height is bigger than the frame height and the user has to scroll down?

Comment: Yes, but you will find that the scroll pane will want to size to accommodate the entire image.  In that case you'll need to implement the `Scrollable` interface, which provide the means to tell the `JScrollPane` the `prefferedViewportSize`

Comment: Thanks for the solution MadProgrammer. How I can update the imagePanel on mouseClicked event?